# liferay-ui view selecting a row

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, alloy-ui

I'm working on a portlet for showing a list of rules, for selection.
And I want to focus the row of content selected on my database (rules variable loaded on `init.jsp`).

What I should do for focusing/highlighting exactly one row?

Should I use `<c:when` `<c:otherwhise` for all the `.jsp`:

I show a list of rules with this code:

```jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<liferay-ui:search-container emptyResultsMessage="there-are-no-products" delta="5">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results>
        <% 
        List<IRRule> tempResults = ActionUtil.getRules(renderRequest);
        results = ListUtil.subList(tempResults, searchContainer.getStart(),
        searchContainer.getEnd());

        total = tempResults.size();
        pageContext.setAttribute("results", results);
        pageContext.setAttribute("total", total);
        %>
    </liferay-ui:search-container-results>

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
        className="com.everis.oriol.inputrules.model.IRRule"
        keyProperty="ruleId"
        modelVar="rule">

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
            name="ruleName"
            property="ruleName"
            />  

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
            name="ruleDescription"
            property="ruleDescription"
            />

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp
            path="/row.jsp"
            align="right"
            />

    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />

</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

In the `init.jsp` file I have...

```jsp
<% 
long groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
List<IRSelect> rulesPas = IRSelectLocalServiceUtil.getRule(groupId);

String rules =  rulesPas.get(0).getRuleName();
%>
```

I exactly want to compare...

```jsp
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
    name="ruleName"
    property="ruleName"
    />
```

with...

```jsp
rules
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: By `focusing` do you mean `highlighting` that table row like changing the background color for that row, or making the elements of the row **`bold`** etc?

Comment: Yes, thats it! I would like to thank you if help me

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I can think of is by setting the `bold` attribute of `<liferay-ui:search-container-row>` tag
which would show the element as **bold** if its value is `true`:

```jsp
<liferay-ui:search-container-row
        className="com.everis.oriol.inputrules.model.IRRule"
        keyProperty="ruleId"
        modelVar="rule"
        bold="<%=rules.equals(rule.getRuleName()) %>">

...

</liferay-ui:search-container-row>
```

Or by setting a CSS class for the entire row if you want more options to style the row:

```jsp
<liferay-ui:search-container-row
    className="com.everis.oriol.inputrules.model.IRRule"
    keyProperty="ruleId"
    modelVar="rule">

    <%
    if (rules.equals(rule.getRuleName())) {
        // here "row" is the ResultRow object, instance for each row
        row.setClassName("my-custom-css-class");
    }
    %>

    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
        name="ruleName"
        property="ruleName"
        />

     ...

</liferay-ui:search-container-row>
```

If you want that only the rule column text in that one row should be shown differently and not the entire row then:

```jsp
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
        name="ruleName"
        property="ruleName"
        cssClass="<%=rules.equals(rule.getRuleName()) ? \"my-custom-css-class\" : \"\" %>"
        />
```